# Ajax actionlink update multiple target id

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

So here's my _Layout.cshtml

```
<body>
<div id="header">  
    <img alt="" src="../../Content/image/header.png" />
</div>
<div id="menuBar"></div>
<div id="navigation">  
    @Html.Partial("NavigationMenu")
</div>
<div id="content">  
    @RenderBody()
</div>
</body>
```

and NavigationMenu.cshtml consist of list of menu by Ajax.actionlink, and also display the item content of the selected menu, when ever the menu is clicked, it has two target to be updated, which is NavigationMenu.cshtml its self, to refresh the item content, and also update div id="content" which is contains @RenderBody which is render my Index.cshtml

And my HomeController

```
return View(menus);
```

So the problem is, when i click any menu, it loads the whole page in my actionlink updateTargetId which is content. I think i need alot of changes, anyone could help this?

## Updated

i got a little changes, since i cant put multiple target id into ajax actionlink's updateTargetId, so i wrap the two div into one div, and then i make that id as updateTarget id.

```
<body>
<div id="header">  
    <img alt="" src="../../Content/image/header.png" />
</div>
<div id="menuBar"></div>
<div id="wraped">
    <div id="navigation">  
        @Html.Partial("NavigationMenu")
    </div>
    <div id="content">  
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

But now the problem is, looks like something wrong, it takes longer to load the page everytime i click on each actionlink, i think it does some kind of looping for rendering or something, anyone can help me with this?